# Не работает Selenium в --headless режиме

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, headless

Делаю парсер и возникла ошибка --headless режиме Selenium не видит элементы.
Искал информацию про это, но так и не нашел то что бы мне помогло.

```
from time import sleep, time
from urllib import request
from urllib.request import urlretrieve, urlopen
from pprint import pprint

import openpyxl
import selenium
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from selenium import webdriver, common
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import ssl
import os

url = "https://megamarket.ru/shop/megamarket-moskva/catalog/bytovaya-tehnika/"
start_time = time()


def parse_product(url):
    print(f"----- PARSE {url}")

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument(
        "--user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0'")


    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)

    driver.get(url)

    sleep(5)

    out_data = []


    products = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "catalog-item")
    pprint(products)
    data = []
    for product in products:
        data.clear()

        data.append(product.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "item-price").text)
        try:
            data.append(product.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "bonus-amount").text)
        except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
            data.append(None)
        data.append(product.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "item-title").get_attribute("title"))

        out_data.append(data[:])

    pprint(out_data)


parse_product(url)

end_time = time()


elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print('Elapsed time: ', elapsed_time)
```

Пробовал разные методы, но ничего не помогает.
Без --headless режиме все работает нормально.